# Why Unity WebGL build catched error "ReferenceError: MyMethodName is not defined"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I want to call javascript function in unity. I created a folder "Plugins" like explained in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html and create a javascript file with extension .jslib and put inside next code:

`

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
    GetBrowserQueryString: () => {
        const qs = window.location.search;
        const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(qs) + 1;
        const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);

        stringToUTF8(qs, buffer, bufferSize);

        return buffer;
    },
    GetVkUserId: () => {
        const qs = window.location.search;
        const match = qs.match(/vk_user_id=(\d+)/);

        const vkUserIdString = match[1];
        const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(vkUserIdString) + 1;
        const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);

        stringToUTF8(vkUserIdString, buffer, bufferSize);

        return buffer;
    }
});
```

`

When i start the build application in browser i see the error "ReferenceError: _GetBrowserQueryString is not defined". How to fix it? What i do wrongly?

In Inspector of jslib file i already checked the WebGL check.

C# code where a trying execute javascript code:

```
public class SocketManager : MonoBehaviour {
    ... bla bla bla
    
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern string GetBrowserQueryString();
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern string GetVkUserId();

    private void Awake() {
        string vkQuery = GetBrowserQueryString();
        string vkUserId = GetVkUserId();
        ... bla bla bla
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it is not `_GetBrowserQueryString` but `GetBrowserQueryString` .. did you maybe misspell this in your according `c#` code .. could you include that in your question?

Comment: i included this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake was that I used arrow functions instead of the usual function naming..... Unity does not know about arrow functions in javascript :(

Fixes:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
GetQueryString: function() {
    const qs = window.location.search;
    const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(qs) + 1;
    const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);

    stringToUTF8(qs, buffer, bufferSize);

    return buffer;
},
GetVkUserId: function() {
    const qs = window.location.search;
    const match = qs.match(/vk_user_id=(\d+)/);

    const vkUserIdString = match[1];
    const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(vkUserIdString) + 1;
    const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);

    stringToUTF8(vkUserIdString, buffer, bufferSize);

    return buffer;
}
```

});